# OpenRecordset not returning usable recordset / .edit not working?

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

Working on a database on Access, trying to run a query to find a record with the latest date and a 'where' condition.
Error returned is "Run Timer Error '3027' Cannot update. Database or object is read-only"

Following conditions:
Button is clicked on a form that contains a text field for 'fCheckInFor'.
Database 'ToolTests' fields
"CheckOut" is dates in format of "3/15/2019 5:35:31 PM"
"CheckIn" is dates in format of "3/15/2019 5:35:31 PM"
"CheckInFor" is a text field
"ToolNumber" is a text field

```
Public CheckInTool as String

Private Sub CheckIn_Click()

CheckInTool = "000"
If Me.fCheckInFor = "" Then
MsgBox "Enter Returning User."

Else
    Dim dbsUE As DAO.Database
    Dim rstUE As DAO.Recordset
    Set dbsUE = CurrentDb
    Set rstUE = dbsUE.OpenRecordset("SELECT Max([CheckOut]) FROM [ToolTests] WHERE [ToolNumber]= '" & CheckInTool & "'")

    With rstUE
    .Edit 'error occurs here
    !CheckIn = Now()
    !CheckInFor = Me.fCheckInFor
    .Update
    End With
MsgBox "Checked In"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "CheckIn"
End If

End Sub
```

So the error throws at the .Edit line, I'm unsure where to go from here. would also be fine with tossing the whole thing and going at it from a different direction.

Comment: Your query is read-only, because of`Sum`and you are missing fields`CheckIn`and`CheckInFor`!

Comment: Try sth. like `SELECT CheckIn, CheckinFor FROM ToolTests WHERE CheckOut IN  (SELECT Max([CheckOut]) FROM [ToolTests] WHERE [ToolNumber]= '" & CheckInTool & "'")`

Comment: So being rather unfamiliar with running these sorts of commands; I plugged that back into the OpenRecordset line, but get a syntax error (Runtime error 3075) " Syntax error in query expression 'CheckOut IN (Select Max(CheckOut)) FROM [ToolTests] WHERE [ToolNumber]='000". "

Comment: You didn't follow the example provided by ComputerVersteher. Misplaced parenthesis in the subquery.

Comment: Edit: determined my mistake.  Parenthesis was set in the wrong position      Set rstUE = dbsUE.OpenRecordset("SELECT CheckIn, CheckinFor FROM ToolTests WHERE CheckOut IN (SELECT Max([CheckOut]) FROM [ToolTests] WHERE [ToolNumber]= '" & CheckInTool & "')")    thank you so much for your help ComputerVersteher

Comment: You're welcome. Please make the solving query a new answer, to guide others with a similar question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, you want to update a record that has a specific `ToolNumber`. So, if you want to use a subquery, you will either need to use that criterion in both the main query and the subquery, or link the subquery with the main query using that field:

```
Set rstUE = dbsUE.OpenRecordset( _ &
  "SELECT CheckIn, CheckinFor FROM ToolTests WHERE" & _
  " CheckOut IN (SELECT Max(CheckOut) FROM ToolTests AS tmp WHERE ToolNumber = ToolTests.ToolNumber)" & _
  " And ToolNumber = '" & CheckInTool & "'")
```

Alternatively, you could simply sort the records in the correct order and update the first one:

```
Set rstUE = dbsUE.OpenRecordset( _ &
  "SELECT CheckIn, CheckinFor FROM ToolTests WHERE" & _
  " ToolNumber = '" & CheckInTool & "'" & _
  " ORDER BY CheckOut DESC")
```